# Spine bone influencing model incorrectly

Tags: rigging

All other bones move correctly. The spine is supposed to bend the body, but it instead does this: [Video of how it moves](https://youtu.be/C1Eu0b-AwHc)

Is there something I did wrong here?

Comment: Share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: you need to correct the weight painting, it looks like the top bone (chest) controls the whole body trunk

Comment: Hi. While videos can be good, ideally all question content should be in the question body, in the form of good descriptions of the issue and images. Thanks.